# Can I make a PL-embedding of a 2-disc into a smooth embedding, and also the other way around?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I have a piece-wise linear (PL) embedding of a disc $D^2$ into $\Bbb R^4$. Now, I want to perform some operation on this disc, but this operation only works with smooth embeddings. So my hope is that I can transition to a smooth embedding, perform the operation, and transition back to a PL-disc.

My questions are therefore:

1. if $\phi:D^2\to\Bbb R^4$ is the PL-embedding, is there another embedding of $D^2$ in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\phi(D^2)$, that agrees with $\phi$ on $\partial D^2$ and is smooth on the interior of $D^2$ (ideally also with curvature bounded linearly in the distance from $\partial D^2$)?
2. if $\psi:D^2\to\Bbb R^4$ is an embedding that is smooth on the interior of $D^2$ and PL on $\partial D^2$, is there a PL-embedding of $D^2$ in an $\epsilon$-neighborhood of $\psi(D^2)$ that agrees with $\psi$ on $\partial D^2$?

Comment: I believe it is an important fact for knot theory that there isn't a way to do this. It is the distinction between smooth and topologically slice knots.

Comment: Your second question seems plausible but I wonder if you mean for the new embedding to be smooth (because it was already PL). Most likely it can be proved with just collar neighborhoods.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Can you give some intuition for why this fails. In my naive intuition I just replace the "pointy ends" and the "sharp creases" of the piece-wise linear embedding by sufficiently close smooth bits.

Comment: At the very least to make that argument work, one would need the local contractibility of the space of such embeddings to argue that the result is isotopic. I’m not sure if that is true or not for PL embeddings. I would recommend asking problem 1 on MO for better discussion.